# hide and show navbar when scroll uiwebview

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, navbar

i need help, i am trying to build a app in which i have a `viewcontroller` with a `uiwebview` and a `navbar` with 2 buttons on it. what i want to do is that when user scroll `uiwebview` navbar automatically hides like slid up sort of. but is not working they way i want it to work. let me post code here.
In `viewdidload` i put this.

```
[webPage.scrollView setDelegate:self];
```

and then i have this method

```
- (void) scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView {
    if(scrollView.contentOffset.y == 0) {
        //show
        NSLog(@"Show");
        [self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:NO animated:YES];
    } else {
        NSLog(@"Hide");
        [self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:YES animated:YES];
        //hide
    }
}
```

it `NSLog` correctly but nothing else `navbar` still stays. :(

Comment: Remember that didScroll will be called for every (almost) pixel change.  The conditions for hiding and showing will need to contain inequalities like offset < someThreshold.

Comment: so what you suggest. sorry i am new. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try this:

**1.** Declare the navigation bar, a constant with your navigation bar height and 2 BOOL variables:

```
UINavigationBar *navBar;

static const CGFloat kNavBarHeight = 60.0f;

BOOL webViewScrollIsDragging;
BOOL webViewScrollIsDecelerating;
```

**2.** In viewDidLoad write the following:

```
 [webView.scrollView setContentInset:UIEdgeInsetsMake(kNavBarHeight, 0, 0, 0)];
 [webView.scrollView setScrollIndicatorInsets:UIEdgeInsetsMake(kNavBarHeight, 0, 0, 0)];
 [webView.scrollView setContentOffset:CGPointMake(0, -kNavBarHeight) animated:NO];
 webView.scrollView.delegate = self;
```

then initialize and add your `UINavigationBar` as a subview to `self.view` at origin (Also make sure that your `UIWebView` has the same origin, i.e (0,0)).

**3.** Implement `UIScrollViewDelegate` methods (Don't forget to add `UIScrollViewDelegate` protocol):

```
#pragma mark - UIScrollViewDelegate Methods
- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
{
    if (scrollView == webview.scrollView)
    {
        if (scrollView.contentOffset.y == 1 && !webViewScrollIsDragging && !webViewScrollIsDecelerating)
        {
            [UIView animateWithDuration:0.3
                                  delay:0.0
                                options: UIViewAnimationCurveEaseOut
                             animations:^(void) {
                                 CGRect navBarFrame = CGRectMake(0,-scrollView.contentOffset.y-kNavBarHeight, self.view.bounds.size.width, kNavBarHeight);
                                 navBar.frame = navBarFrame;
                             }
                             completion:nil];
        }
        else
        {
            CGRect navBarFrame = CGRectMake(0,-scrollView.contentOffset.y-kNavBarHeight, self.view.bounds.size.width, kNavBarHeight);
            navBar.frame = navBarFrame;
        }

        if (scrollView.contentOffset.y < -kNavBarHeight)
        {
            [webview.scrollView setScrollIndicatorInsets:UIEdgeInsetsMake(fabsf(scrollView.contentOffset.y), 0, 0, 0)];
        }
    }
}

- (void)scrollViewWillBeginDragging:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
{
    if (scrollView == webview.scrollView)
    {
        webViewScrollIsDragging = YES;
    }
}

- (void) scrollViewDidEndDragging:(UIScrollView *)scrollView willDecelerate:(BOOL)decelerate
{
    if (scrollView == webview.scrollView)
    {
        webViewScrollIsDragging = NO;
    }
}

- (void) scrollViewWillBeginDecelerating:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
{
    if (scrollView == webview.scrollView)
    {
        webViewScrollIsDecelerating = YES;
    }
}

- (void) scrollViewDidEndDecelerating:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
{
    if (scrollView == webview.scrollView)
    {
        webViewScrollIsDecelerating = NO;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 12):

Easy as add this on the ViewController implementation file (.m):

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.webView.scrollView.delegate = self;
}  

#pragma mark - UIScrollViewDelegate Methods

- (void)scrollViewWillBeginDragging:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
{
    self.lastOffsetY = scrollView.contentOffset.y;
}

- (void) scrollViewWillBeginDecelerating:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
{
    bool hide = (scrollView.contentOffset.y > self.lastOffsetY);
    [[self navigationController] setNavigationBarHidden:hide animated:YES];

}
```

AND don't forget to add `UIScrollViewDelegate` protocol in the header file (.h) :

```
@interface MyViewController : UIViewController <UIScrollViewDelegate>
    ...
@end
```

Comment: Thank you! Please don't forget to add the `lastOffsetY` property: `@property (nonatomic) CGFloat lastOffsetY;` on the `@interface` ;)

Answer (score 1):

In iOS8.0 and later 
just use one line code:

```
self.navigationController.hidesBarsOnSwipe = YES;


/// When the user swipes, the navigation controller's navigationBar & toolbar will be hidden (on a swipe up) or shown (on a swipe down). The toolbar only participates if it has items.
//  @property (nonatomic, readwrite, assign) BOOL hidesBarsOnSwipe NS_AVAILABLE_IOS(8_0) __TVOS_PROHIBITED;
```

When sliding down will hide the navigation bar (and become a transparent state bar), when the slide will be displayed on the navigation bar, the process with animation